# Resharper suggesting to convert Using statements to single "await Using"?

Tags: async-await, resharper, using, c#-8.0

Resharper suggests to improve using statements with await key word to single line await using statements. As an example, the following code snippet :

```
    private async Task<string> ReadResponseAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originalBody = context.Response.Body;

        try
        {
            using (var responseStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = responseStream;
                await _next(context).ConfigureAwait(false);

                var response = context.Response;
                response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(response.Body))
                { 
                    var responseContent = await responseReader
                    .ReadToEndAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);

                    response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    await responseStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
                    return responseContent;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Response.Body = originalBody;
        }
    }
```

after applying successive Resharper suggestions the code becomes the following :

```
    private async Task<string> ReadResponseAsync(HttpContext context)
    {

        var originalBody = context.Response.Body;

        try
        {
            await using var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
            context.Response.Body = responseStream;
            await _next(context).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var response = context.Response;
            response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            using var responseReader = new StreamReader(response.Body);
            var responseContent = await responseReader
                .ReadToEndAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            await responseStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            return responseContent;
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Response.Body = originalBody;
        }
    }
```

Are these two code snippets similar ? What is actually being improved here ? I am not understanding this feature of C# for using statements.

Comment: This is just syntactical sugar introduced in C# 8

Comment: `await using` is for anything that implements `IAsyncDisposable` which allows it to have an asynchronous dispose method.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ you're right, this using async disposables, also introduced in c# 8

Comment: @DetectivePikachu of course it is, but they are two different things. The first doesn't release resources asynchronously, the second one does of course and is better for OP; it's enabling the consumer to dispose operations without blocking the main thread.

Comment: I said you're right bruh what more do you need?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two things changed when you accepted that recommendation:

1. `await using`, which you can use on types that implement the new [`IAsyncDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable). It's the same as the regular `using`, except it calls `DisposeAsync()` instead of `Dispose()`.
2. The change from a `using` block, to just a statement. This recommendation is just to minimize nesting in your code. Once the object falls out of scope, then `Dispose()`/`DisposeAsync()` is called. You can read more about it in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Those are two separate features that you can use independently of each other (you can use `await using` with a block, or use `using` as a statement), but both are brand new in the language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in what scenarios do we prefer one over the other ?

Comment: Use `await using` whenever you can (you can't always - it depends if the object is `IDisposable` or `IAsyncDisposable`). To understand the benefits of asynchronous programming, you can read the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). The `using` statement vs. block is really just preference. You might prefer a block when you want to control the [scope](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samng/2007/11/09/local-variable-scoping-in-c/) of the object.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel Luci !

Answer (score 3):

C# 8.0 introduced some Syntax sugar around using:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations

If you apply using in the declaration of a variable of limit scope (the try block for `var responseReader`), that scope will be used as the bounds of the using.

All it realy does, is allow you to skip writing a few brackets. However they will still be in the compiled code. This makes the whole thing more readable.